# How can I convert an m4v video to a widely viewable format using ffmpeg?

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg

I have a m4v video generated by iMovie. I want to use ffmpeg to generate a widely viewable video on Windows. I cannot assume that the viewer will have VLC (or any other sophisticated viewer). It needs to be viewed by what is a default installation of Windows 7.

How do I do this? I tried `ffmpeg -i video.m4v video.avi`, and that did not directly work for my users. They say they get audio, but no video.

Comment: When you say "widely viewable video" do you mean in a codec that Windows natively supports? My understanding is that if the m4v file doesn't have DRM (which yours won't) then you can rename it to `.mp4` and it'll play happily on many platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.m4v -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict experimental \
-movflags +faststart video.mp4
```

But note, that this will re-encode your video file.

Comment: +1. As my mac did not accept h264, I did: ffmpeg -i  in.m4v -strict experimental -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 out.avi, hopefully it is the same